# Where to put Feature Requests?

Tags: feature-request

Where should I post feature requests? So that nobody tells me, that it is the wrong place and so that also developers might see it very quickly...?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1190/599

Comment: Features for Blender.SE?  If so, then you can post it on [Meta Blender SE](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/) or [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No not the sequence editor.. For the whole Blender application in general...